# Representations of S3

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I am currently working on representation theory in my algebra class and we are asked the the following question. I was hoping I could get some verification of my proofs although I'm pretty sure that my solution for 3 is wrong as I have found the answer elsewhere using character theory, and it does not match up with mine. Part of the reason I am seeking help is that my linear background is rather weak, so I don't really understand what is going on in the background with the eigenvectors and what have you.

Let $V$ denote the standard representation of $S_3$. Using the ad hoc approach presented in Fulton and Harris, compute the decompositions into direct sums of irreducible representation of the following representations of $S_3$

1. Sym$^2V$, Sym$^3V$, and Sym$^kV$ for all $k\in\textbf{N}$
2. $\bigwedge^2(V),\bigwedge^3(V)$, and $\bigwedge^k(V)$ for all $k\in\textbf{N}$
3. $V^{\otimes2},V^{\otimes3}$, and $V^{\otimes k}$ for all $k\in\textbf{N}$

For all of the problems, I am taking $\tau=(123)$ and $\sigma=(12)$. For 1, I am fairly certain I am correct so I will post only my answer and if that is wrong I will gladly put up my whole proof.

Sym$^2(V)$ decomposes as $V\oplus U$ where $V$ is the standard representation of $S_3$ and $U$ is the trivial representation, Sym$^3(V)$ decomposes as $V\oplus V$, and in general if $k$ is even, then Sym$^k(V)$ decomposes as $\bigoplus\limits^{\frac{k}{2}}V\oplus U$, and if $k$ is odd, then Sym$^k(V)$ decomposes as $\bigoplus\limits^{k-1} V$.

For 2, I am less sure.

Recall that $\bigwedge^2(V)=\textbf{C}$-span$\{u\wedge v|u,v\in V\}$ where $u\wedge v=\frac{1}{2}(u\otimes v-v\otimes y)$. Using the same setup as in problem 1, we see that a basis for $\bigwedge^2(V)$ is $\{\alpha\wedge\beta\}$ as $\alpha^2=\beta^2=0$, and $\beta\wedge\alpha=-\alpha\wedge\beta$ where concatenation is understood to be the wedge product. We compute that $\tau(\alpha\wedge\beta)=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\otimes\beta-\beta\otimes\alpha)$ and likewise that $\sigma(\alpha\wedge\beta)=\frac{1}{2}(\beta\otimes\alpha-\alpha\otimes\beta)$. Since $\tau$ has sign 1 and $\sigma$ has sign -1, we conclude that $\bigwedge^2(V)$ is equivalent to the alternating representation.

For $\bigwedge^3(V)$ we follow the same procedure and get that our ``basis" is $\{\vec{0}\}$, meaning that our vector space is the zero vector space. Therefore, $\bigwedge^3(V)$ does not decompose into a sum of irreducible representations of $S_3$. Likewise, we have that $\bigwedge^k(V)$ does not decompose into a sum of irreducible representations of $S_3$ for all $k\geq 3$ where $k\in\textbf{N}$.

For 3,

Recall that $V^{\otimes2}=\textbf{C}$-span$\{u\otimes v|u,v\in V\}$ where $\otimes$ is not commutative. Using the same setup as in problem 1, we see that a basis for $V^{\otimes2}$ is $\{\alpha^2,\alpha\beta,\beta\alpha,\beta^2\}$ where we understand the operation to be the tensor product. Thus, $\tau(\alpha^2)=\omega^2\alpha^2,\tau(\alpha\beta)=\alpha\beta,\tau(\beta\alpha)=\beta\alpha$, and $\tau(\beta^2)=\omega\beta^2$. Likewise, $\sigma(\alpha^2)=\beta^2,\sigma(\alpha\beta)=\beta\alpha,\sigma(\beta\alpha)=\alpha\beta$, and $\sigma(\beta^2)=\alpha^2$. Thus, $\{\alpha^2,\beta^2\}$ is a subspace of $V^{\otimes2}$ with dimension 2 that is $S_3$ invariant, so it is equivalent to the standard representation. Likewise, $\{\alpha\beta,\beta\alpha\}$ is a subspace of $V^{\otimes2}$ with dimension 2 that is $S_3$ invariant, so it is equivalent to the standard representation. Therefore, $V^{\otimes2}$ decomposes as $V\oplus V$.

For $V^{\otimes3}$ we follow the same procedure using $\{\alpha^3,\alpha^2\beta,\alpha\beta\alpha,\beta\alpha^2,\alpha\beta^2,\beta\alpha\beta,\beta^2\alpha,\beta^3\}$ as our basis. Thus, we get that $\tau(\alpha^3)=\alpha^3,\tau(\alpha^2\beta)=\omega\alpha^2\beta,\tau(\alpha\beta\alpha)=\omega\alpha\beta\alpha,\tau(\beta\alpha^2)=\omega\beta\alpha^2,\tau(\alpha\beta^2)=\omega^2\alpha\beta^2,\tau(\beta\alpha\beta)=\omega^2\beta\alpha\beta,\tau(\beta^2\alpha)=\omega^2\beta^2\alpha$, and $\tau(\beta^3)=\beta^3$. Likewise, $\sigma(\alpha^3)=\beta^3,\sigma(\alpha^2\beta)=\beta^2\alpha,\sigma(\alpha\beta\alpha)=\beta\alpha\beta,\sigma(\beta\alpha^2)=\alpha\beta^2,\sigma(\alpha\beta^2)=\beta\alpha^2,\sigma(\beta\alpha\beta)=\alpha\beta\alpha,\sigma(\beta^2\alpha)=\alpha^2\beta$, and $\sigma(\beta^3)=\alpha^3$. Thus, $\{\alpha^3,\beta^3\},\{\alpha^2\beta,\beta^2\alpha\},\{\alpha\beta\alpha,\beta\alpha\beta\},\{\beta\alpha^2,\alpha\beta^2\}$ are all subspaces of $V^{\otimes3}$ with dimension 2 that are $S_3$ invariant, and thus are all equivalent to the standard representation. Therefore, $V^{\otimes3}$ decomposes as $V\oplus V\oplus V\oplus V$.

In general, if $k\in\textbf{N}$ then each pairing of linear combinations of $\{v_1\otimes...\otimes v_k\}$ where each $v_i\in\{\alpha,\beta\}$ forms $2^{k-1}$ subspaces of dimension two. Therefore, $V^{\otimes k}$ decomposes as $\bigoplus\limits^{2^{k-1}}V$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that not all $2$-dimensional representations will be the standard representation. You need them to be irreducible for that, and you never show this (it will not hold for all of them). One way to see that this approach is not right is that for example the second symmetric and exterior powers are both subrepresentations of the second tensor power.

Comment: I don't have time to read this proof right now, but I just want to chime in and say that the proof is *greatly* simplified with character theory. I recommend just reading enough to get to symmetrix/alternating decomposition. For example, chapter $2$ of fulton and harris' book will do (just the first 3/4 pages really.)

Comment: Holy moly. Yes, character theory is both easy to learn at this level, and will reduce this massively.

Comment: That is the impression I've gotten from everything I've read, but we aren't allowed to use character theory.

Comment: @AndresMejia I disagree with that. Yes, character theory makes this particular thing easier, but getting an idea of how to work with the actual representations will be very useful for other cases where characters might not be available, such as over other fields.

Comment: @user104729 See my comment to Andres

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I agree with you. Good point.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I didn't mean to devalue the worth of working with particular representations, but its worth knowing when the theory can reduce the difficulty of a problem significantly-- as is the case with representations of finite groups, and especially the classical ones that we deal with most of the time. The bang for buck in learning enough character theory to solve this problem seems to me reason enough to learn it. Of course, I'm not an expert in representation theory (At all) so I could be wrong.

Comment: @AndresMejia My point is that obtaining a solution to this problem is pretty much irrelevant. The whole idea of an exercise is to learn to work with the objects in question, in this case representations. Sometimes later theory can then make those specific problems easier, but that does not make the exercise worse. Just because you do this exercise now without character theory does not mean you should not learn character theory a bit later, it just means that if you use character theory for it, you learn less.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As mentioned, my linear is rather weak. I essentially took some statements made by my professor and tried to apply them to each question without really understanding the meaning behind them. My professor has mentioned computed eigenspace decomposition of the $tau$ and $sigma$ operators to determine which subspaces are invariant. I've tried looking this up but I'm having a hard time finding something I can follow with at my level. Would you walk me through this, or link me to a page that describes the process in detail?

Comment: If your linear algebra is lacking, then you need to do something about that, as the main point of representation theory is to be able to apply knowledge of linear algebra to other areas.